# Select customers with multiple addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have a customer table and want to select customers with multiple addresses.

I create the following query, but the customer with `Customer_ID = 105` with the same address and different account is included in my result set.

```
select *
from [Customer]    
where Customer_ID in (select [Customer_ID]       
                      from [Customer]
                      group by [Customer_ID]
                      having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try adding a `count(distinct)` on Address.

Comment: `group by [Customer_ID], Account`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from [Cutomer]    
where Customer_ID in (
   select [Customer_ID]       
   from [CuatomerA]
   group by [Customer_ID]
   having count(distinct [Address]) > 1
)
```

Comment: Hi Dougp. Your solution is good

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window fuction, which is likely to be more efficient than using a self-join

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *,
     count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID)
   FROM Customer c
) c
WHERE count > 1;
```